# CORS Post request working locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have two projects in the same solution. One is an ASP.NET MVC project and the other is a Web API project. On my local machine the MVC project is running on `http://localhost:2302/` I have enabled CORS in the Web API project using the following code in the WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
namespace WebServices
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:2302", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionApi", "{controller}/{action}/");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a controller where I have a controller like the following:

```
namespace WebServices.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUploadManager _uploadManager;

        public UploadController(IUploadManager uploadManager)
        {
            _uploadManager = uploadManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadImage()
        {
            var result = await _uploadManager.UploadImage(Request);

            return result.Success
                ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result)
                : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
        }
    }
}
```

UploadImage method exists inside a repository class where I have the upload logic there. Finally I call my service using the XMLHttpRequest JavaScript object like the following:

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
var uploadPercent;

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
    var percent = Math.floor((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
    uploadPercent = percent;
}, false);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (event.target.readyState === event.target.DONE) {
        if (event.target.status !== 200) {
            console.log('error in uploading image');
        } else {
            var status = JSON.parse(event.target.response);
            var imageGuid = status.returnId;
            var imageUrl = status.returnString;
        }
     }
};

xhr.open('post', 'http://localhost:4797/Upload/UploadImage', true);
var data = new FormData();
var files = $('#uploadInput')[0].files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append('file' + i, files[i]);
}

xhr.send(data);
```

The above code works good when I test it on my local machine. But when I deploy it on an actual server it does not (Of course I have changed all the links to the respective links for my domain - also the projects are deployed separately but on the same server). When the OPTIONS request is sent I receive 400 Bad Request status code. I have read a lot of information on the internet but nothing seems to help me. This is the request sent by the browser:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,el;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/Account/ExtraDetails/91a832ee-496c-46a7-ac4b-dfb89bbc8fc5
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
```

and the response received:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:69
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 15 Dec 2014 22:42:11 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I noticed that no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is created in the response when the application is deployed but as far as I know it should be. Do I need to do any further configuration on the server or am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried using  config.EnableCors() or config.EnableCors("*","*","*")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to be handling the preflight `Options` *requests*.

`Web API` needs to respond to the `Options` request in order to confirm that it is indeed configured to support `CORS`.

To handle this, all you need to do is send an *empty response* back. You can do this inside your actions, or you can do it globally like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

This extra check was added to ensure that old `APIs` that were designed to accept only `GET` and `POST` requests will not be exploited. Imagine sending a `DELETE` request to an `API` designed when this *verb* didn't exist. The outcome is *unpredictable* and the results might be *dangerous*.

Also I suggest enabling *Cors* by **web.config** instead of `config.EnableCors(cors);`

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Please note that the *Methods* are all individually specified, instead of using `*`. This is because there is a bug occurring when using `*`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped a lot. Right now the OPTIONS request returns a status code of 200. But if you look at the response in developer tools it returns an error stating that "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.". Then the upload starts and it is processed successfully. Although it works, the error that appears seems a little strange. Do you have any explanation for it?

Comment: You could try use `Response.End();` right after `Response.Flush();`. Also you should investigate if there's other part of your Web API which sets headers before `Application_BeginRequest`.